# Run processes in separate environments in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

SO I have a script that creates its own environment variables which are then accessed by a c++ program.

I want to run multiple instances of this program, and while doing that I want to keep them running on different environments to avoid the separate processes accessing each others environment variables and getting mixed up.

At the moment what Im doing is 
open a new cygwin window and:
. ./script.sh

But I have to open a new window each time.

Answer (score 0):

Just run as many `./script.sh >outN 2>errN &` in one window as you like (note: use different numbers N per invocation; do **not** source them with the dot). This way they cannot overwrite each others environment variables because each script is executed in a separate shell.